# Android Studio how to pass data from recyclerview to next activity textview? JAVA

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple order app. I have a recyclerview that contains products with their id, price, and quantity. When I click on a product, it opens the product details activity and I want it to display the product name and price in two textviews. I'm not sure how to transfer the data from the recyclerview to display in the textviews of product details activity.

Comment: This approach (also as shown in the one answer) is not exactly the suggested way... all one needs is the ID.

Comment: Did you try searching google or this site? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541581/recyclerview-click-to-pass-data-to-new-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple code for Pass Data**

**FirstActivity**

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this , SecondActivity.class);
    sendIntent.putExtra("firstData" , "HelloWorld1");
    sendIntent.putExtra("secondData" , "HelloWorld2");
    sendIntent.putExtra("thirdData" , "HelloWorld3");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
    String firstData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstData");
    String secondData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondData");
    String thirdData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("thirdData");
    textview1.setText(firstData);
    textview2.setText(secondData);
    textview3.setText(thirdData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data in the Intent itself by adding them as extras.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    String id = "your_id";
    int quantity = 0;
    double price = 0.0d;

    intent.putExtra("Id",id);
    intent.putExtra("Quantity",quantity);
    intent.putExtra("Price",price);
```

And then in your next Activity, you can extract these from Intent.

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras != null) {
    String id = extras.getString("Id");
    int quantity = extras.getInt("Quantity");
    double price = extras.getDouble("Price");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple code for Pass Data Recyclerview TO NextActivity**

**RecycleView Adpter**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent sendIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this , SecondActivity.class);
         sendIntent.putExtra("firstData" , holder.textview.getText().toString());
         sendIntent.putExtra("secondData" ,  holder.textview1.getText().toString());
         sendIntent.putExtra("thirdData" ,  holder.textview2.getText().toString());
         startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_frame);
    String firstData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstData");
    String secondData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondData");
    String thirdData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("thirdData");
    textview1.setText(firstData);
    textview2.setText(secondData);
    textview3.setText(thirdData);}
```